# Why doesn't this almost-identical value class work?

Tags: scala, value-class

As promised at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html, this works:

```
class Wrapper(val self: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def toHexString: String = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(self)
}
println(12.toHexString)
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
class Wrapper(val self: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def whyNot:      String = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(self)
}
println(12.whyNot)
```

Why not? The only thing I changed is the name of the method!

Here is the error message:

```
error: value whyNot is not a member of Int
    println(12.whyNot)
               ^
```

---

<sup>Yes, I have double-checked for schtupit Unicode characters inside `whyNot`.</sup>

Comment: I just found a clue: The working one still works even if I comment out `class Wrapper { ... }`. Apparently, Scala is invoking the built-in `RichInt` class but ignoring my `Wrapper` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Predef.scala [defines](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L472) the implicit conversion from Int to RichInt:

```
  @inline implicit def intWrapper(x: Int)         = new runtime.RichInt(x)
```

When you call `println(12.toHexString)` it's not looking at your Wrapper, it's doing the implicit conversion to RichInt and using the method [defined there](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/runtime/RichInt.scala#L45).

If you want your own implicit conversion, you need to define it using the [`implicit` keyword](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html):

```
implicit class Wrapper(val self: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def whyNot:      String = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(self)
}
println(12.whyNot)  // prints "c"
```

Comment: Ah, that explains it all, including why there's no `implicit` in the `RichInt` source. And indeed when I add `implicit` before `class Wrapper`, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think it *whould* compile.

Integers don't have a `whyNot` method. `Wrapper`s have a `whyNot` method, but `12` is an `Int`, not a `Wrapper`.

You need to call `whyNot` on a `Wrapper` object:

```
new Wrapper(12).whyNot
// => "c"
```

Comment: I'm hoping to make `whyNot` work on `Int`s by automatically wrapping them, like the example of `3.toHexString` [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). Do I have to put `implicit` in front of `class Wrapper`? If so, do you know why there is no `implicit` before `RichInt` [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/runtime/RichInt.scala#L1)?